# Expected value of a variable given a probability distribution

Tags: r, regression, probability, distributions, expected-value

I have fitted some data with a normal and gamma distribution. But I need to find the expected value of my variable. For example is **x** is my data (mine is not normal) and fit them into a normal and gamma distribution. My expected value is not the same as the mean? Also for the gamma distribution the mean is **alpha/beta** which gives me the same as the mean.

```
x=rnorm(100)
m=mean(x)
v=var(x)
no=dnorm(x,m,sqrt(v))
gama=dgamma(x, ((m^2)/v),m/(v))
```

PS: But I think what my professor wanted me to do was: I was given a dataset of two variables and I needed to see which distribution fitted better, (it was a gamma), but after doing this the problem asked for the two distributions(Normal and gamma) to find the expected value. But I don't get if it has to be equal to the mean(x) in R. Or if I have to make an integral for this

PS2: I think for a simple way to ask. If I already fitted my data lets say to a normal(4,8) then my expected value isn't equal to 4? The same is for the gamma distribution, given alpha and beta, my mean isn't equal to alpha/beta?

Comment: `?rgamma` explains what the mean of the generating random variable is given the parameters you pass. If you want the mean of the sample data, that would be `mean(x)` as you've computed. If you want to compare x to a distribution, maybe a Q-Q plot, like `qqnorm(x)` or `qqplot(x, rgamma(length(x), m^2/v, m/v))` (assuming m^2/v and m/v are appropriate estimators) would help? I'm not really clear on what the question is.

Comment: @Frank, I don't undestand this either. But I think what my professor wanted me to do was: I was given a dataset of two variables and I needed to see which distribution fitted better, (it was a gamma), but after doing this the problem asked for the two distributions(Normal and gamma) to find the expected value. But I don't get if it has to be equal to the mean(x) in R. Or if I have to make an integral for this.

Comment: @Frank I think for a simple way to ask. If I already fitted my data lets say to a normal(4,8) then my expected value isn't equal to 4? The same is for the gamma distribution, given alpha and beta, my mean isn't equal to alpha/beta?

Comment: The answer depends on what procedure you used to estimate the Normal and Gamma parameters.  To illustrate, one procedure is *moment matching* (aka *Method of Moments*), in which you select parameter values for which the expectation and variance of the fitted distributions exactly agree with the mean and variance of your data.  But many other procedures work differently and do not guarantee there is such an agreement.  Please, then, tell us how you estimated the parameters.